# How to Pass an Array of Objects (Node.JS) to an EJS file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I am trying to create a form. You enter your info, hit submit, and then a new page opens showing you what you submitted. There's also a button at the bottom that will redirect to a new page with all of the different contact information you entered.

I am having a problem passing a variable from my JavaScript file to my EJS file (formserver.js to contacts.ejs). I keep getting an error that my array of objects has not been passed (line 16 of contacts.ejs).

I was wondering if anyone could help explain why my Object array is not being passed into the EJS file, and what I could do to remedy that.

Here is the code:

formserver.js

```
var connect = require("connect");
var logger = require("morgan");
var http = require("http");
var ejs = require('ejs');
var bodyparse = require('body-parser');


var app = connect()
    .use (logger('dev'))
    .use (bodyparse())
    .use (serve);

http.createServer(app).listen(3000);

var allInfo = new Array;

function serve(req, res)
{
    //console.log("Entered ", req.url);
    var gender = req.body.gender;
    var firstName = req.body.firstName;
    var lastName = req.body.lastName;
    var street = req.body.street;
    var city = req.body.city;
    var state = req.body.state;
    var zip = req.body.zip;
    var phone = req.body.phone;
    var email = req.body.email;
    var contact = req.body.contact;
    var mail = req.body.mail;

    var form = {gender: gender, fname : firstName, lname : lastName, street : street, 
            city : city, state: state, zip: zip, phone : phone, email: email, mail: mail }



    if (req.url == "/mailer")
    {

        })
}
```

contacts.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p> <% allInfo %> </p> 
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Contact by mail?</th>
    </tr>

    <% for (var person in allInfo) { %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= allInfo[i].gender %>. <%= allInfo[i].fname %> <%= allInfo[i].lname %></td>              
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td> <%= street %>, <%= city %>, <%= state %> <%= zip %></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><%= phone %></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><%= email %></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><%= mail %></td>
    </tr>

    <% } %>
</table>
```

mailer.ejs

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <form action = "/submit" method = "post">
        <fieldset style = "width:500px">
        <p>
            <div>
            <input type = "radio" name = "gender" value = "Mr"> Mr. 
            <input type = "radio" name = "gender" value = "Mrs"> Mrs. 
            <input type = "radio" name = "gender" value = "Ms"> Ms. 
            <input type = "radio" name = "gender" value = "Dr"> Dr. 
            </div>
        </p>
        <p>
        <div>
            <label  for = "first">First Name: </label>
            <input type = "text" name = "firstName" required>
            <label for = "last">Last Name:</label>
            <input type = "text" name = "lastName" required>
        </div>
        </p>
        <p>
        <div>
            <label for = "street" > Street: </label>
            <input type = "text" name = "street" location = "street">
            <label for = "city" name = "city"> City: </label>
            <input type = "text" name = "city" location = "city">
        </div>
        </p>
        <p>
        <div>
            <label id = "state" for = "state" name = "state">State: </label>
            <select name = "state" id = "state">
                <option value = "" disabled = "disabled" selected = "selected"> </option>
                <option value = "NJ""> NJ </option>
                <option value = "NY"> NY </option>
                <option value = "PA"> PA </option>
                <option value = "CT"> CT </option>
            </select>
            <label for = "zip"> Zip: </label>
            <input type = "text" name = "zip" location = "zip">
        </div>
        </p>

        <p>
        <div>
            <label for = "phone" >Phone:</label>
            <input type = "text" name = "phone" location = "phone">
        </div>
        </p>

        <p>
        <div>
            <label for = "email" >Email:</label>
            <input type = "text" name = "email" location = "email">
        </div>
        </p>

        <p>
        <div>
            <label for = "contact" name = "contact"> How may we contact you? </label>
            <input type = "checkbox" name = "contact" value = "yPhone"> Phone </input>
            <input type = "checkbox" name = "contact" value = "mail"> Mail </input>
            <input type = "checkbox" name = "contact" value = "yEmail"> Email </input>
            <input type = "checkbox" name = "contact" value = "any" checked> Any </input>
        </div>
        </p>
        </fieldset>

        <div>
            <button type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "submit"> Send me spam forever! </button>
        </div>
    </form>
        <p><a href = "/contacts"> View list of contacts! </a></p>
    </body>
    </html>

submit.ejs
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div><strong> Contact Information Submitted </strong></div>
    <div><strong> Name: <%= gender %>. <%= fname %> <%= lname %> </strong></div>
    <div><strong> Address: <%= street %>, <%= city %>, <%= state %> <%= zip %></strong></div>
    <div><strong> Contact by Phone: <%= phone %> </strong></div>
    <div><strong> Contact by Mail: <%= mail %></strong></div>
    <div><strong> Contact by Email: <%= email %> </strong></div>


    <p><a href = "/contacts"> View list of contacts! </a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
render (res, "contacts", allInfo);
```

to this:

```
render (res, "contacts", {allInfo: allInfo});
```

Without the object wrapper the template will just be passed an array, it won't know that you called it `allInfo`.

You've got an inconsistency in the template too, using both `i` and `person` for the iteration variable. I suggest changing it to this:

```
<% for (var i = 0 ; i < allInfo.length ; i++) { %>
```

Alternatively you could change it to a `forEach`.

You've also got problem with some of the fields, such as this:

```
<%= street %>
```

which should be this:

```
<%= allInfo[i].street %>
```